# Copy database data to new database with LinqToSql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

I have a SQL CE database in my Windows Phone application. I have decided that I need to secure the database as seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202861%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). The problem is, is that the database was originally created without a password, thus, not encrypting it. I would like to move all data over to a new encrypted database.

What is the best way to migrate the data and retain the relationships? I tried to do this (db is the new database, and context is the old)

```
db.Groups.InsertAllOnSubmit(context.Groups);
```

but it throws the error

> An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an entity that is not new, perhaps having been loaded from another DataContext.  This is not supported.

Do I have to manually spin to each object, create them in the new database, then perform lookups to associate the entities?

Answer (score 1):

You should use external tools for database migration. You can generate sql script to create your database structure and then use Import and Export Data tool to copy the data over to the new database. I would not do it programatically.

Comment: Are you able to give me more information on these external tools? Remember I'm working with LinqToSql/Sql CE.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use AttachAll instead of InsertInsertAllOnSubmit:

```
db.Groups.AttachAll(context.Groups);
```